# Please help me with some info about selling used PC parts online

Tags: pc

Could not find a suitable stack exchange website for my topic, so I'm asking here. Please forgive if it's wrong.
I want to sell my used CPU, Mobo, Gpu, RAM, PSU seperately or if customer wants i can sell my whole system(including cabinet, cooler, peripherals etc everything) together. But i have no experience on selling stuff online. I don't know how customer and I can trust each other. How can i trust customer that he will pay after getting the product ? or the payment happens before i send my items? Also how can i convince customer about the good condition of my products? Are just some images enough for that? I'm from India. I've found few websites to do the selling such as - cashify.in , techenclave.com , .olx.in , quikr.com , shopify.in , sellmypc.in , ebay.in , Amazon Trade-In , .facebook.com/marketplace . But i don't know which websites are good. Please recommend me some best websites for this purpose.

Comment: Yea you are wrong, but I think this does not fit any SE website, but I also could be wrong

Comment: Try asking on reddit.  Or just google search for reviews on some websites